# Como gerar aplicação iOS com React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Alguém pode me dizer como funciona o processo de gerar um aplicativo pra iOS?

Supondo que tenha o código pronto só tenha que gerar o app, preciso necessariamente ter um iMac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro: React-native é "learn once, write anywhere.", quer dizer, "Aprenda uma vez, escreva em qualquer lugar.", ou seja, o código do APP pra Android normalmente precisa de modificações para o iOS.

Agora, quanto a pergunta, sim precisa gerar o .ipa no Xcode, para isso necessitando de um Mac, e o arquivo é gerado no próprio Xcode.